# Why when checking if touching with the finger on the character it's not accurate by checking the finger position and the character position?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, mobile

```
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class MobileControls : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text text;

    private bool move = false;
    private RaycastHit hit;
    private Slider[] sliders;
    private Dropdown dropDown;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount == 1 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            text.text = "";

            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(0).position);

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                if (hit.point == transform.position)
                {
                    move = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    move = true;
                    GameObject sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
                    sphere.transform.position = hit.point;
                    sphere.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
                    sphere.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
                    Destroy(sphere.GetComponent<Collider>());
                }
            }
        }
        
        if(Input.touchCount == 2)
        {
            text.text = "Press Space !";
        }

        if(move)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, hit.point, Time.deltaTime * 2f);

            Vector3 direction = hit.point - transform.position;
            Quaternion rot = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);

            transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, rot, 100 * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to make that no matter where I touch the character on it middle top bottom anywhere it will set move to false only if I'm touching somewhere else on the screen make move true.

but when I touch the character the hit.point position is no the same as the character position.  it's close but never accurate so move is always true.

I tried this to check the touch position if it's close enough to the character but still it's not working as before:

```
private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount == 1 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            text.text = "";

            Vector3 touchPos = Input.GetTouch(0).position;

            bool touchingPlayer = (touchPos - Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position)).magnitude < 0.1f;

            if (touchingPlayer)
            {
                move = false;
            }
            else
            {
                move = true;
                Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touchPos);
                if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
                {
                    GameObject sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
                    sphere.transform.position = hit.point;
                    sphere.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
                    sphere.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
                    Destroy(sphere.GetComponent<Collider>());
                }
            }
        }

        if (Input.touchCount == 2)
        {
            text.text = "Press Space !";
        }

        if (move)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, hit.point, Time.deltaTime * 2f);

            Vector3 direction = hit.point - transform.position;
            Quaternion rot = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);

            transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, rot, 100 * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

working code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class MobileControls : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text text;

    private bool move = false;
    private Collider playerCollider;
    private RaycastHit hit;

    private void Start()
    {
        playerCollider = GetComponent<Collider>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount == 1 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            text.text = "";

            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                if (hit.collider == playerCollider)
                {
                    move = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    move = true;
                    GameObject sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
                    sphere.transform.position = hit.point;
                    sphere.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
                    sphere.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
                    Destroy(sphere.GetComponent<Collider>());
                }
            }
        }

        if (Input.touchCount == 2)
        {
            text.text = "Press Space !";
        }

        if (move)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, hit.point, Time.deltaTime * 2f);

            Vector3 direction = hit.point - transform.position;
            Quaternion rot = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);

            transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, rot, 100 * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hit.Point returns the exact point of collision of the ray with the collider. So checking that with transform.position will not return true in most cases. Just replace with a collider check and see if your code works.